# Iterating over elasticsearch response and creating aggregation function within one ES query

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch query which returns the top 10 results for a given querystring. I now need to use the response to create a sum aggregation for each of the 10 top results. This is my query to return the top 10:

```
GET search/
{
  "index": "my_index",
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": {
        "query": "hello world",
        "fuzziness": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the response from the above request, I generate a list of the 10 `org_id`s and iterate over each of these ID. I have to make another request using the query below (where `"org_id": "12345"` is the first element in my array of IDs).

```
POST _search/my_index
{ "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "org_id": "12345"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
      "aggregation_1": {
        "sum": {
          "field": "dollar_amount"
        }
      },
      "aggregation_2": {
        "sum": {
          "field": "employees"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

However, I think that this approach is inefficient because I have to make a total of 11 requests which won't scale well. Ideally, I would like to make one request that can do all of this.

Is there any functionality in ES that would make this possible, or would I have to make individual requests for each search parameter? I've looked through the docs and can't find anything that involves iterating over the array of results.

---

EDIT: For simplicity, I think having 2 requests is fine for now. So I just need to figure out how to pass through an array of `org_ids` into the 2nd query and do all aggregations in that 2nd query.

E.g.

```
POST _search/my_index
{ "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "org_id": ["12345", "67891", "98765"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
      "aggregation_1": {
        "sum": {
          "field": "dollar_amount"
        }
      },
      "aggregation_2": {
        "sum": {
          "field": "employees"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To start you can aggregate on one step (so 2 requests in total)

I am taking a look about the fuzziness, but I don't see how make a one shot query.

Edit: are your org_id unique (= id of documents?), can you describe your data (how org_id are linked with the fuzziness query)?

```
{ "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "org_id": "12 13 14 15 16 17 18...." 
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_org_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "org_id"
      }
    },
   "aggs": {
      "aggregation_1": {
        "sum": {
          "field": "dollar_amount"
        }
      },
      "aggregation_2": {
        "sum": {
          "field": "employees"
        }
      }
    }
} 
}
```

Comment: I should have clarified the org_id more. It is not unique per doc, rather it is just a field in the document. So a given org_id can be present in multiple documents. The aggregation is done such that for all documents returned for that org_id, it sums the amount columns. The fuzziness is related to the first query, which is a search using name rather than ID. That query returns a list of org_ids that I then use to do the aggregation.

Comment: Ok, well i posted the querry to get agg in a single request. As we cant use fuzziness in aggregation, i dont see how made all in one single querry.